# How do I encrypt with AES, CBC, and Nopadding

Tags: go, aes

```
func AESEncryptWithNopadding(origData []byte,key []byte,iv []byte) (string, error) {
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    blockMode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, iv)
    crypted := make([]byte, len(origData))

    blockMode.CryptBlocks(crypted, origData)
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(crypted), nil
}
```

I try to Aes encript with nopadding but

OUTPUT: panic: crypto/cipher: input not full blocks

Comment: The length of the plaintext for AES in [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC)) mode must be an integer multiple of the block size (16 bytes for AES). Otherwise, padding is necessary, which ensures that this condition is met. Is the condition for your plaintext without padding fulfilled? There are also stream cipher modes that do not require padding, e.g. [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode), which provides authentication in addition to confidentiality.

Comment: But in Java there seems have a function call **AES/CBC/NoPadding**How did they do it?

Comment: For encryption a plaintext is expected which fulfills the above condition (otherwise a corresponding exception is thrown: _IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length not multiple of 16 bytes_). For decryption a possible padding from encryption is not removed.